# How do I detect if SKProduct already purchased as consumable in app purchases before?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I imported StoreKit and set my code for consumable purchase and set a sandbox tester. I have three buttons. Each one will buy a separate product. Here is my problem:

When my sandbox tester tries to purchase the same product again and presses the same button, Firebase analytics says:

> "Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported".

Ok, fine. But how I can get this as a response from AppStore? Where does Firebase get this from?

When I look at `SKPaymentTransaction.transactionState` enum, there is no case about it. I tried to check cases and print something to console, like this:

```swift
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("purchased")
            break
        case .restored:
            print("restored")
            break
        case .failed :
            print("failed")
            break
        case .deferred:
            print("deferred")
            break
        case .purchasing:
            print("purchased")
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked `transaction.error`, but no error either.

This code prints nothing when the purchase fails from duplicate purchase. How can I get at least an error here?

What should I do?

My goal is show an alert and tell the client "You already purchased this".

Comment: Firebase is not doing the right thing. Consumable items can be purchased many times. When a user purchases a consumable item a subsequent time then it is delivered as a standard purchase transaction. In fact, even when a user purchases a non-consumable item that they have already purchased, the normal transaction is delivered, but the user is not charged a second time.  At no time does purchasing an item already purchased, consumable or non consumable, deliver an error.

Comment: @ShanmugarajeshwaranR No, I could not, but as Paulw11 said, consumable purchases are meant to be purchased many times. It's like "You purchased a cup of coffee yesterday, why do you want to purchase another one".  I changed my approach to use consumable purchases in normal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulw11 said in the comments, consumable purchases are meant to be purchased many times. I was wrong. Trying to stop multiple purchases from a consumable purchase is like "You purchased a cup of coffee yesterday, why do you want to purchase another one today?". Of course, someone can want another cup of coffee today.

I changed my approach to using consumable purchases in the usual way.